# divorce separation

Tags: vocabulary

Is "divorce separation" a phrase in English? I read a lot but could find nowhere. I found the two words being used differently. Do the two make some specific meaning while being used together?

Comment: The two words "divorce separation" occur consecutively in English fairly often, but they would rarely if ever represent a "subject" (i.e. - a ***noun***). They'd normally be just a couple of "noun adjuncts" adjectivally modifying the true noun, as in *a divorce separation **agreement*** (some kind of legal agreement about how to divvy up a couple's assets when they get divorced and therefore wish to lead separate lives). The other common type of result returned by googling the collocation will be contexts where they're both mentioned because they're near-synonyms (as with "divorce breakup").

Comment: Strangely, searching for "divorce separation" (in quotation marks for exact match), doesn't find any results, but "divorce separation agreement" does. Even so, it sounds very strange to me (work experience includes legal editing). I can imagine a "separation agreement" and a "divorce agreement", but not a "divorce separation agreement".

Comment: Why are you asking about this phrase? Did you see it somewhere? Please provide the full context.

Answer (score 3):

A divorce is an official dissolution of marriage - once you get it, in the eyes of the law you are no longer married to your ex-spouse.

A separation is a broader concept of living apart from your spouse. What this entails depends on the local law - some places consider you separated just based on the fact that you do not live together, others require the separation to be adjudicated by a court and might involve a custody agreement, property division and so on.

The important distinction is that while separated, you're still married - you're not allowed to marry again (unless polygamy is allowed in the first place), and if you decide to get back together you do not need to remarry, just cease the separation.

Answer (score 1):

They are partial synonyms, with *divorce* sounding more final. I don't know what they might mean when put together as a phrase.